# How do I stop a mouseleave event when entering another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it so that when I hover over one of my timeline items and navigate to the drop down menu, the mouseleave event will not fire and the menu will continue to display.  Only when leaving both the menu and the timeline item do I want the menu to not display.

The mouseenter and mouseleave events are set on:

```
$(".trek_timeline_day .activity_link")
```

Comment: can u show me jsfiddle for this

Answer (score 1):

Put the timeline and the menu into one div and register the events for the whole div. So something like this:

```
<div class="wholediv">
    <div class="timeline">...</div>
    <div class="menu">...</div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
$( '.wholediv'  ). etc.
```

Comment: I unfortunately can't do this due to other limitations.  If I did that my menus would get cut off with an overflow hidden css property.

Comment: I think you can override this css property anyhow, can't you?

Comment: No, I can't since it is a child element of my timeline.

Comment: @JasonBiondo: Sure you can. You just have to refactor your code so it all matches up! As I said before, throw it up in a jsfiddle or jsbin or something and I am more than happy to help you out.

Comment: @JasonBiondo: So add a new class for the menu and change the css property for this class which will override the timeline property.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend implementing some form of jQuery Menu Aim, similar to Ben Kaman's Amazonish smart menu - http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `.hover_info` div inside the `.activity_link` (so there is one `.hover_info` inside each `.activity_link`), the `mouseleave` event will not get fired when you enter the `.hover_info` div because it's inside the `.activity_link` element.

Comment: As mentioned in the other comment, I can't do that because my menu would get cut off. Any other solutions?

Comment: If that is a problem, I would suggest that you refactor your code, because I cannot think of any way that would be a problem, if you just write your html and css in a proper fashion. If you need help, throw it up on a jsbin or jsfiddle or something, and I'd be more than happy to help you out.